# How to get auditd started in CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004?

Tags: centos, auditd

I did `sudo yum reinstall audit` on my server running CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004.

When I tried `systemctl start auditd` it failed. When I ran `journalctl -xe` I received the following output:

```
-- Unit auditd.service has begun starting up.
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app auditd[158318]: No plugins found, not dispatching events
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app auditd[158318]: Error setting audit daemon pid (File exists)
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app auditd[158318]: Unable to set audit pid, exiting
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app auditd[158318]: The audit daemon is exiting.
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app auditd[158318]: Error setting audit daemon pid (Permission denied)
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app systemd[1]: auditd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: /sbin/augenrules: No change
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: No rules
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: enabled 1
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: failure 1
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: pid 2094
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: rate_limit 0
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: backlog_limit 8192
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: lost 0
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: backlog 0
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: backlog_wait_time 60000
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: enabled 1
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: failure 1
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: pid 2094
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: rate_limit 0
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: backlog_limit 8192
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: lost 0
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: backlog 0
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: backlog_wait_time 60000
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: enabled 1
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: failure 1
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: pid 2094
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: rate_limit 0
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: backlog_limit 8192
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: lost 0
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: backlog 1
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app augenrules[158319]: backlog_wait_time 60000
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app systemd[1]: auditd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 15 20:19:02 my_app systemd[1]: Failed to start Security Auditing Service.
-- Subject: Unit auditd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Unit auditd.service has failed.
```

Comment: Did you try the obvious: removing the old PID file?

Comment: No because I didn't see in the message where to find the old PID file - how do I do that?

Comment: Most likely the usual place, somewhere in the `/run` directory. Do make sure a copy of auditd isn't actually still running, though.